# "/" route not displaying homepage, giving 403 forbidden Laravel 5

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I've deployed a test Laravel 5 application onto a development server. 
The application is successfully installed but when I go to the domain that points to my application. It doesn't load the Laravel 5 homepage. Instead it gives me a 403 Forbidden Error.

I'm on an nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem is your server root is not pointing to `public` folder of your project, where index.php is located. Double-check your vhost configuration to be sure everything is fine.

Nginx access and error logs should help you with this. Also, check the same vhost on your local environment with development tools turned off.

Comment: if ($host ~ ".*webrtc-dev.*\.message360.*") {
        set $sub "${sub}/public";
} This is how my vhost_secured config is set up. it is pointing to the public folder. This is how it's been and I'm still getting the error